# Scala: How to get an Enumeration "Value" from a literal

Tags: scala

Given to following `Enumeration`...

```
object TokenType extends Enumeration {

  type TokenType = Value

  val Activation = Value("activation")
  val Authentication = Value("authentication")
  val Reset = Value("reset")
}
```

... I get the a value as a string like this:

```
scala> val str = Reset.toString
str: String = reset
```

But how can I get a `TokenType.Value` starting from the string `reset`?

scala> val v: TokenType = ???

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this: `TokenType.withName("reset")`